# PHP automatic mail... "No input file specified."

Tags: php, email

I have written a php file which sends email which is running via browser correctly.
.I want to automatically send mails to user so i set up a job using "cron" after every 15 minutes

My php file name is "mail.php" and it is under folder "/public_html/myfolder/mail.php"

I have writen the command as

```
php -f /public_html/myfolder/mail.php
```

but it is showing error as "No input file specified."

so i tried using

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /public_html/myfolder/mail.php
```

but the error was

"Could not open input file: /public_html/suvichar/mail.php

i have given the 777 permission to "mail.php"

can you please tell me what might be the issue
can anybody give me exact command for cron to execute php file

Comment: Can the owner run the cron? r/w permission are not enough, if not set to the right owner.

Comment: I have a CPanel through which i can add cron jobs i just need to specify the command to execute..and i have given 777 permision

Comment: I have given 777 (r/w/x) permission for all U/o/G
to  "mail.php"

Comment: Is public_html really in the root of your file system? I would assume  not. If I'm correct, use the full path to the file, or the relative path from the directory you're actually in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally public_html is located in the /var/www (or similar directory). For FreeBSD the location of public_html is /usr/home/<username>/public_html. You already stated you put execute permissions. For any one else looking to add execute permission on a file you run this at the command prompt:

```
 chmod +x scriptname.php
```

Second you need to make sure you include the path to php at the top of your php file

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
```

--- OR --- (FreeBSD) and for you according to your question

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/php
```

When you call the cron job in your crontab file you use

```
 crontab -e
```

Add this line to the file and save: 15 * * * *     /absolute/path/to/mail.php

```
# (This states that the script will run every 15 minutes everyday.)
# ------------- minute (0 - 59)
# | ----------- hour (0 - 23)
# | | --------- day of month (1 - 31)
# | | | ------- month (1 - 12)
# | | | | ----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
# | | | | |     * - Any day/month/hour
 15 * * * *     /absolute/path/to/mail.php
```

Comment: I would also check your php script to make sure you do not need to pass a file with it.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys it finally worked for me
You guys were right public_html wasnt root directory of my server.
Actullay via FTP i was able to see only structure below

/public_html.......

the Absolute path was

**/home/primary_ftp_username**/public_html/myfolder/file_name.php

thank you :D